NextUI accordion item customization | How do I justify the heading's items?
I want this space between the title and the indicator: example 
My code:
<Accordion className=" w-4/6 border-2 border-stone-200 rounded-md shadow-md" itemClasses={{indicator: "ml-2"}}>
                            <AccordionItem key="1" aria-label="Accordion 1" title="Planos de Compliance" classNames={{heading: "flex justify-between"}} className="Gotham bg-white rounded-t-md p-2" indicator={({isOpen}) => isOpen ? <IndicatorOpen></IndicatorOpen> : <IndicatorClose></IndicatorClose>}>
                                {planosCompliance()}
                            </AccordionItem>
</Accordion>

but this is what I get: try
I tried to modify the heading's css to display flex and use justify-content: space-between. I don't know why doesn't work.
